# Fortran - String with unknown characters into substrings

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to put an input string into sub-string arrays. The number of data in the input file are less than 10 but unknown. The number of spaces between each data is also unclear.

Example:

```
Asd  B       Cwqe21 Ddsw      Eww
```

I am quite novice to Fortran, so I do not know which format I should use. My problem is that I do not know the number of data (here I assumed that there are 5), so how can I make the code work?
I tried the following which did not work:

```
CHARACTER (LEN=100), DIMENSION(10) :: string
READ (1,*) (string,I=1,10)
```

It seems that the error I got was because there was no 6th string to read and put into string(6).

I tried using the "Index" to find the space, but since I do not know how many spaces are in the string, it did not help me.

Comment: As given in a comment on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090384/unknown-number-of-data-set-in-fortran-input-file, use a format `A`. Also, look at the "Related" questions on the right of this page, first of which is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319631/reading-a-string-with-spaces-in-fortran?rq=1

Comment: Don't post the (almost) identical question again. Instead, edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Read it into a single string with format `(A)`.  Test each character to see if it is NOT a blank -- if so, you have the start of the next sub-string.  Either use index to find the next blank to find the end of that substring, or test each character.   Copy the substring into a character array.  Repeat...

Comment: in fairness this version is much clearer -- at this point you ought to go delete the other one (and next time revise questions instead of posting a new one )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is more or less elegant/efficient than the standard approach in M.S.B's comment, but an interesting alternative.

```
  integer istart,nw
  character (len=100) line,wd,words(100)
  open(1,file='t.dat')
  read(1,'(a)')line
  istart=1
  nw=0
  do while(len(trim(line(istart:))).gt.0)
     read(line(istart:),*)wd
     istart=istart+index(line(istart:),trim(wd))+len(trim(wd))
     nw=nw+1
     words(nw)=trim(wd)
  enddo            
  write(*,*)trim(line)
  write(*,*)('/',trim(words(k)),k=1,nw),'/'
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

An inefficient approach that is simple to program is to try to read the maximum number of items, and if this fails to successively try to read one fewer items until the read is successful, as shown below:

```
program xread_strings
integer, parameter   :: nw = 10
character (len=1000) :: text
character (len=20)   :: words(nw)
integer              :: i,ierr,nread
text = "Asd  B       Cwqe21 Ddsw      Eww"
nread = 0
do i=nw,1,-1
   read (text,*,iostat=ierr) words(:i)
   if (ierr == 0) then
      nread = i
      exit
   end if
end do
if (nread > 0) write (*,*) "read ",nread," words: ",("'"//trim(words(i)) // "' ",i=1,nread)
end program xread_strings
! g95 Output:
! read  5  words: 'Asd' 'B' 'Cwqe21' 'Ddsw' 'Eww'
```

Comment: interesting solution -- you ought to show the steps needed for reading from a file.