# Fortran read from console--continue even if carriage return with no input

Tags: fortran

Here is a code snippet.

```
      flist = 0.0
      write (*, 778)
 778  format ('Enter temperature to save frequencies to frq.dat or n to bypass ', $)
      read(*, *, iostat =rerr) fstring
      if (fstring.ne.'n') then
      ....
```

What I want to do is to detect only a carriage return with no input when the read statement executes instead of requiring some input like 'n'.

I absolutely cannot figure out how to do this.

I have not figured out anything to try except instead of 'n', I tried'' which just hangs until an input is typed.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are after, but if you want carriage return to leave `fstring` as an empty string, you can't do this with list-directed input. So, why are you using list-directed input and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As a general rule, that is: don't use list-directed input [to read string input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6319631/3157076).

Answer (score 0):

With list-directed input to a CHARACTER variable, yes you must enter a nonblank value -- or (edit) enter a slash to indicate 'no data' (actually no *more* data, but in this case you want none), or indicate EOF by implementation-dependent means (typically control+D on Unix or control+Z,return on Windows), which prevents any further input from the same file (here `*` = 'console') which may or may not be what you want.

If you use formatted input `read (*, '(A)') fstring` with `character(len=whatever) fstring` or equivalent, then just hitting return -- or more generally receiving an empty or blank line/record -- sets `fstring` to all blanks, which you can detect by comparing `fstring .eq. ''` (or `==` in f90 up, although the nonstandard output format `$` is normally used only in code from before f90 standardized nonadvancing I/O) because CHARACTER comparison pads with blanks.

Comment: Your first paragraph appears to be missing mention of record separators?

Comment: @francescalus: how so? list-directed skips record separators (or pedantically the end-of-record condition they represent and cause), so they have no effect on and are irrelevant to this Q. (Ditto namelist, but that's not in this Q.)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
read(*, '(a)', iostat =rerr) fstring
if (fstring .eq.'') then
```

Comment: Some of your very short answers already attracted downvotes. I suggest reading [answer]. If you propose some code in an amswer, please explain what it does. The explanation can be very short, but writing just "What about" is like writing nothing at all.

Comment: It is obvious what the code means and above all it solves the problem. What's the goal of saying many words?

Comment: It is obvious to you. The goal is explained in the link I provided, albeit only for links, which are slightly different. Anyway, this is just a suggestion, I am not going to downvote these answers if they are not incorrect. But someone else might or you may lose some potential upvotes.